# Proper way of using Laravel Collect for creating combination

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create combination from the below list, but I am not sure how to parse through the results as the results dynamicaly changes each time.

Here is the `result` I receive through my form,

```
{"1":["Medium"],"2":["White","Blue"]}
```

How do I parse the above result to get the possible combination (eg below).

```
product_combination 
-------------------
Medium-White
Medium-Blue
....
....
Medium
Medium-White-Large
```

I am using Laravel,  I would be later storing the data in the database for reference

I appreciate if you could explain me how to handle such data.

Edit:
I came up with an alternative

```
$input = json_decode('{"1":["Medium", "Large"],"2":["White", "Blue"]}', true);
$result = array();
        foreach ($input as $array) {
            $result = array_merge($result, $array);
        }
        print_r(collect($result)->crossJoin(collect($result)));
```

Result for the above code is as follows

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Medium
                    [1] => Medium
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Medium
                    [1] => White
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Medium
                    [1] => Blue
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => White
                    [1] => Medium
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => White
                    [1] => White
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => White
                    [1] => Blue
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Blue
                    [1] => Medium
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Blue
                    [1] => White
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Blue
                    [1] => Blue
                )    
        )    
)
```

In this case the arrays are auto populated but the results are longer than the Mr PaulH approach

Comment: please explain where the Medium and Medium-White-Large come from

Comment: I would like to create the possible combinations from the above response that I get. The Medium and Medium-White-Large  for reference. I am looking to create the results in the above desired way.

Comment: So, you want to cross join
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-crossjoin
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-crossjoin

Comment: I am aware of this. But I cannot pass the data as object for the crossjoin to process. I need assistance on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
// convert json input string to array
$input = json_decode('{"1":["Medium", "Large"],"2":["White", "Blue"]}', true);

// convert both parts of array to collections, 
// crossJoin all the combinations and
// join the combinations in strings  
collect($input[1]) 
    ->crossJoin(collect($input[2]))
    ->map(function($combination) {
        return collect($combination)->join('-');
        
        // alternatively:
        // return implode('-', $combination);
    });

// ['Medium-White', 'Medium-Blue', 'Large-White', 'Large-Blue']
```

Alternative, without Laravel collection:

```
<?php
$input = json_decode('{"1":["Medium", "Large"],"2":["White", "Blue"]}', true);

foreach($input[1] as $in1) {
    foreach($input[2] as $in2) {
        $out[] = $in1 . '-' . $in2; 
    }
} 

return $out;
// ['Medium-White', 'Medium-Blue', 'Large-White', 'Large-Blue']
```

Extend to 'dynamic' as requested in comments

```
<?php
function combine($inputs) {
    $inputs = json_decode($inputs, true);
    $results = array_shift($inputs); 
    while ($inputs) {
        $newresults = [];  
        $newinputs = array_shift($inputs);
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            foreach ($newinputs as $new) {
                $newresults[] = $result.'-'.$new;
            }
        }
        $results = $newresults;
    }
    print_r($results);
}
```

Test:

```
combine('{"1": ["Medium", "Large"]}');
combine('{"1": ["Medium"], "3": ["Cotton", "Silk"]}');
combine('{"1": ["Medium", "Large"], "2": ["White", "Blue"], "3": ["Cotton", "Silk"]}');
```

Test result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Medium
    [1] => Large
)
Array
(
    [0] => Medium-Cotton
    [1] => Medium-Silk
)
Array
(
    [0] => Medium-White-Cotton
    [1] => Medium-White-Silk
    [2] => Medium-Blue-Cotton
    [3] => Medium-Blue-Silk
    [4] => Large-White-Cotton
    [5] => Large-White-Silk
    [6] => Large-Blue-Cotton
    [7] => Large-Blue-Silk
)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, But I am getting this error -- Call to a member function join() on array", exception:

Comment: Also the above list is dynamic. This can grow. How do I handle that too.. for eg: {"1":["Medium"],"2":["White","Blue"],"3":["Cotton","Silk"],....,...}

Comment: print_r(collect($input[1])); result : Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
          [0] => Medium
        )

)

Comment: Updated the above print_r(collect($input[1])); .. Still getting the error --- Call to a member function join() on array", exception:

Comment: print_r(collect($input[2])); result :  Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => White
            [1] => Blue
        )

)

Comment: I think the issue is in this line - return $combination->join('-');. I removed the `->join('-')`. Its now yeilding the result - Array
(
    [0] => Medium
    [1] => White
)
Array
(
    [0] => Medium
    [1] => Blue
)
Array
(
    [0] => Medium
    [1] => Black
)

Comment: Would you please assist me in converting the code to pick dynamic values. I have no clue how to get it done.

Comment: replace return $combination->join('-'); with implode('-', $combination);

Comment: Thank you, It worked... Any suggestion on converting the code to pick dynamic values

Comment: you need set the primary data you want to crossjoin , then put another data to crossjoin, all i can thought

Comment: I came up with another alternative ..         // $result = array();
        // foreach ($input as $array) {
        //     $result = array_merge($result, $array);
        // }
        // print_r(collect($result)->crossJoin(collect($result)));
your thoughts please

Comment: thats equal to my thought lol, u set the collect($result) then add data to crossjoin($result) xD

Comment: I have edited the question.. But the results for your answer is sweet where are mine is picking up all the possible combination

Comment: remember to map combinations and implode results when you need a readable data, good luck :)

Comment: Sure.. Thank you very much